# Why is my PHP IP query returning a Google ip address on Chrome for Mobile

Tags: php, google-chrome, ip

I have the following script in a php file to get the user's IP..

```
<?php
function GetIP()
{
    foreach (array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED', 'REMOTE_ADDR') as $keyip)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($keyip, $_SERVER) === true)
        {
            foreach (array_map('trim', explode(',', $_SERVER[$keyip])) as $uip)
            {
                if (filter_var($uip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE) !== false)
                {
                    return $uip;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
$ip = GetIP();
echo $ip;
?>
```

and it works fine when I run it from my computer or MY phone (using Chrome browser), returning my correct IP address in Argentina. However, when I run it from both of my brother's phone using the Chrome browser it is giving me 66.249.85.30 which seems to be a Google proxy (hostname: google-proxy-66-249-85-30.google.com). When I use the regular internet browser on the phones it gives the correct IP address.

When I do an online search to get my IP address using the Chrome browser on my brothers' phones, it (whatismyip.com) returns the correct IP address and not the Google IP, so it has to be possible.

Does anyone know why it is doing this and what can be done to get the real IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this could be the Data Compression Proxy used by Chrome mobile browser when the [Data Saver](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/data-compression) feature is turned on.

> The core optimizations that allow us to reduce overall data usage are
>   performed by Google servers. When Data Saver is enabled, Chrome opens
>   a connection between your phone and one of the optimization servers
>   running in Google's datacenters and relays all non-encrypted HTTP
>   requests over this connection.

To check if this feature is enabled on the user's browser, you can check if the `save-data` HTTP Header exists and is set to 'on'. You can obtain their 'real' IP using the [X-Forwarded-For](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) header in this case - the header information can be manipulate so not guaranteed.

It looks like your code is looking for that header, but it could be overcomplicating things and might be returning the proxy IP before the real. I haven't got a PHP server set up to test but you could do a dump of the `$_SERVER` variable or output some information within the loop to see what is happening.

Comment: Ahh it looks like the `if (filter_var($uip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE) !== false)` filter was coming up false for my actual IP. I am confused, as my IP is not in the Reserved Range nor is it in the Private Range (My IP is 181.91.***,**)

Comment: @Alesana Is `$uip` actually set to 181.91...? I don't see any reason it should fail in that case. If you are running via localhost then it would fail because of loopback address being filtered. What you want to do is log out the variables onto the page when opening the page, and then visit it from your brother's phone.

Comment: Good call, the `$uip` for `HTTP_FORWARDED` is actually set to `for=181.91.***.**`, not just the IP alone. I don't know why `$_SERVER` is doing this.

Comment: Check `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`. This gives you comma separated list, and the first one SHOULD be your real IP.

Comment: As you can see in my code I do check for `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`. When I logged out the variables (and checked `print_r($_SERVER)`) it wasn't set :/

Comment: I created a local php server and then installed the [Data Saver extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/data-saver/pfmgfdlgomnbgkofeojodiodmgpgmkac/related). I ran `<?php echo '<pre>' . var_export($_SERVER, true) . '</pre>'; ?>` in my php page and `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` maps to an array with a single IP, my actual IP address. `REMOTE_ADDR` maps to the proxy IP. I'm not sure why the forwarded one is not set for you, but I guess the proxy server just didn't set it. Could you parse response of `HTTP_FORWARDED` and use that if the other is not set? Simple string replace?

Comment: That was my solution, I just wanted to make sure that there wasn't something else wrong that's causing it. Thank you!